# Remove UIGesturerecognizer from UIObject

Tags: ios

Is there a way of completely removing all UIGestureRecognisers from any UIObject such as a UItextView? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
[photoView removeGestureRecognizer:[photoView.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
```

NOTE: I don't want to disable them because I would like to assign other gestures recognizers in future.

Comment: check whether photoView is nil

Comment: How does it "doesn't work" ? Do you get a runtime crash ? What's the log ?

Comment: Can you log [photoView.gestureRecognizers count] prior to trying to removing it ?

Comment: It just doesn't remove the gesture

Comment: I believe that `UITextView` recreates its gestures as you enter and exit editing mode (possibly because the context sensitive menu for cut/copy/paste changes? not sure).

Comment: Sorry, but why downgrading my question?? Please provide feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all, instead of just:

```
[photoView removeGestureRecognizer:[photoView.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
```

You could:

```
while ([photoView.gestureRecognizers count] > 0)
    [photoView removeGestureRecognizer:[photoView.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
```

By the way, be aware that some standard text controls will recreate gesture recognizers as you enter and exit editing mode, so you might have to repeat this process accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to stop any Gesture recognizer.

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
    {

    // return NO when you want to stop.

if ( [gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] ) {
        // Return NO for views that don't support Taps
    } else if ( [gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]] ) {
        // Return NO for views that don't support Swipes
    }

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Since i need to use each recogniser once and then remove it is this ok? How can I use this code?